# Newbie question: Static countdown timer based on server time

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

A client wants a launch page which will show a static countdown and when the countdown is finished the user will be redirected to another page.

The launch is like an event for all users, so I want to make it hard for the user to access the redirected page before the countdown reaches zero - therefore I think it is best to base it on server time instead of the users/clients time, so that the user cant tinker with the time.

The countdown should also reach zero at approximately the same time across (two) different time zones.

I've found a few different scripts and approaches to this across the web, but I can't seem to get it to work.

My jQuery code right now is like this

```
var end = new Date(Date.UTC(2020,12-1,10,12,00,00)) ;
var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;
var _day = _hour * 24;
var timer;

function serverTime() {
  var time = null;
  $.ajax({url: 'www.myserveradress.com/server_time.php',
      async: false, dataType: 'text',
      success: function(text) {
          time = new Date(text);
      }, error: function(http, message, exc) {
          time = new Date();
  }});
  return time;
}

function showRemaining() {
    var now = serverTime();
    var distance = end - now;
    if (distance < 0) {

        clearInterval(timer);
        window.location.href = '/surprise.html';

        return;
    }
    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + 'dagar ';
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += hours + 'timmar ';
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += minutes + 'minuter ';
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + 'sekunder';
}

timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
```

And the php script like this:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Fri, 1 Jan 2010 00:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8"); // MIME type
$now = new DateTime();
echo $now->format("Y,m,d,H,i,s")."\n";
?>
```

Everything is working fine (the redirection, the countdown and the time zones) **but what is not working is the server time.**

It is a Frankenstein creation of different codes so I am pretty sure I have messed up somewhere, my guess is that I've messed up the *serverTime* function or in the *showRemaining* function (specifically how the *now* variabel should show the result of the *serverTime* function).

Sorry if this is badly explained, I am a newbie after all. And sorry if this has, in some way, been answered before. I have searched but found no answer which is helping me out.

Thanks!

Comment: How is the server time "not working"? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry! Let me explain: The php script seems to work fine, when launched it shows the date in the same date format as in the jQuery script (var end = new Date(Date.UTC(2020,12-1,10,12,00,00)) ;) 
But I guess that I can't seem to get the result of the php script to be "displayed" correctly in the "now" variable in the "showRemaining()" function. This is at least my guess to why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you're using does not work synchronously. The statement `$.ajax` will not wait for the fetch (as you might expect) and will pass on to the next statement immediately. When you `return time`, the variable `time` is not assigned yet.

You should let the `success` callback of `$.ajax` to trigger update instead. When the fetch finish, jQuery.ajax will call that callback with the fetched result.

```js
var end = new Date(Date.UTC(2020,12-1,10,12,00,00)) ;
var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;
var _day = _hour * 24;
var timer;

// returns another callback for setInterval to use.
function serverTime(callback) {
  // the below callback will be actually called on every setInterval trigger.
  return function () {
    var time = null;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'www.myserveradress.com/server_time.php',
        async: false, dataType: 'text',
        success: function(text) {
            time = new Date(text);
            callback(time); // ****** see this ********
        },
        error: function(http, message, exc) {
          time = new Date();
        },
    });
  }
}

function showRemaining(now) {
    if (now < end) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        window.location.href = '/surprise.html';
        return;
    }

    // gets milliseconds difference
    var distance = end.getTime() - now.getTime();
    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + 'dagar ';
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += hours + 'timmar ';
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += minutes + 'minuter ';
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + 'sekunder';
}

timer = setInterval(serverTime(showRemaining), 1000);
```

Also, your `server_time.php` needs to return a string that Javascript's Date know how to read. E.g. [RFC-2822 timestamp](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14).

```php
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Fri, 1 Jan 2010 00:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8"); // MIME type
$now = new DateTime();

echo $now->format(DateTimeInterface::RFC2822);
```

Relevant documentation:

- [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
- [window.setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)
- [RFC 2822 timestamp](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14)
- [DateTimeInterface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer!
But I am now getting a NaN response on the countdown. I guess that my knowledge in this is to limited to understand what I need to change in order to get a correct result. How is the `var distance` calculated in your example? It substracts the  `new Date()` from  `var end` with what? I guess that I don't understand how `now` is connected with the server time.

Comment: The variable `now` is a string. Your `server_time.php` should return a string accepted by [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) instead a string of comma separated value.

Comment: The safest value would be [RFC-2822 timestamps](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#page-14)

Comment: I'm not sure about the RFC-2822 timestamps and how to implement that. But I edited my php like this and that **worked!** `<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Fri, 1 Jan 2010 00:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8"); // MIME type
$now = new DateTime();
echo date_format($now, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>`

Comment: But, now I got another problem, the time zones doesn't seem to work. When I change the time zone on my computer, so does the time remaining. Should I also base that variable on a server time? And if, how?

Comment: Your date format do not have timezone information. Browser will interpret the time according to its own timezone. Thus the problem. Please see my edited answer to see how to return RFC2822 timestamp.

Comment: That seem to fix it! You are the best! Thank you for your patience with a noob like me. I've learned quite a lot.